# How can I exclude a piece of code inside a core animation block from being animated?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, core-animation

I have an core animation block where I call a method that will load a view controller. there is an custom transition between two view controllers happening. However, when the view controller builds up the interface, all this stuff is affected by core animation. Although it results in some interesting effects, I don't want that ;)

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"jump to view controller" context:self];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.55];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

// some animated property-changes here...

[self loadViewControllerForIndex:targetIndex]; // everything that happens in this method shall not be animated

UIViewController *controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:targetIndex];
[controller viewWillAppear:YES];
[controller viewDidAppear:YES];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Unfortunately I can't move that part out of the block.

Answer (score 10):

You should be able to suppress animations for a section of the UIView animation block by wrapping that section in a CATransaction and disabling animations for it:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];    

// Changes to disable animation for here
[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as +[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES] within an animation block?

Comment: @Andrew - Yes, `-setDisableActions:` was added in iPhone OS 3.0 and Snow Leopard, and is identical to the `-setValue:forKey:` I use above.  I had grabbed this from some older code I used in 2.0.

Comment: This works nicely for me, thanks for sharing this. Also, it's better than the [UIView setAnimationsEnabled: NO] approach that someone else posted here (and apparently deleted last night). Because that approach simply turned off *all* animation, including one the caller may have set up for itself.

Comment: There is also a block based alternative `[UIView performWithoutAnimations:(void (^)(void))actionsWithoutAnimation]`. Available since iOS7