# Exclude view from UIAnimation

Tags: uitableview, core-animation, pull-to-refresh

I have made a "pull-to-refresh" and when finished updating the inset is removed using animation block. However I'm getting unwanted animations in the custom uitableviewcell, see movie:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rZcEBm_fTUc&feature=youtu.be

Watch carefully at the bottom. I found this:
[How can I exclude a piece of code inside a core animation block from being animated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914959/how-can-i-exclude-a-piece-of-code-inside-a-core-animation-block-from-being-anima)

But don't know how to use it, here is the code that I'm using:

```
    id animation = ^{
        //Remove the contentinset
        [self.tableView setContentInset:refreshView.initialInset];

    };

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction |UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:animation
                     completion:nil];

    [refreshView endAnimation];
}
```

Thankful for any help on this matter!

Answer (score 0):

I was not reusing my UITableViewCells correctly. Before i removed all subviews from the cell and added them again, which is the wrong way to do it.

By using "reuseIdentifier" for my different UITableViewCells and only instantiating the UILabels and UIButtons once the problem disappeared (along with a lot of other problems)